# Count rows with the same pattern in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar to the one below and I need to count how many times the same row pattern repeats in this data frame.

```
start_id | end_id | type | id
1        | 2      | a    | 1
2        | 5      | a    | 2
1        | 3      | b    | 3
2        | 5      | a    | 4
1        | 3      | b    | 5
```

The result I want is this:

```
start_id | end_id | type | n
1        | 2      | a    | 1
2        | 5      | a    | 2
1        | 3      | b    | 2
```

I tried the following code, but it is not merging the records, it is returning the same rows as they are, just adding a new column with the counter, which is bad for my analysis:

```
Sumary <- clear_filt_trip  %>%
    group_by(start_id, end_id, type) %>% 
    add_count(across(everything()))
```

I tried using `summarize` but it's just repeating the columns.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Look at the dupe-link, and in your head replace all mentions of "mean by group" with something like "length" or "number of rows" or similar, leading to the same set of possible solutions (within `dplyr` or not).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(start_id, end_id, type) %>%
  tally() %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   start_id end_id type      n
#      <dbl>  <dbl> <chr> <int>
# 1        1      2 a         1
# 2        1      3 b         2
# 3        2      5 a         2
```

### base R

```r
aggregate(. ~ start_id + end_id + type, data = dat, FUN = length)
#   start_id end_id type id
# 1        1      2    a  1
# 2        2      5    a  2
# 3        1      3    b  2
```

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(start_id = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1), end_id = c(2, 5, 3, 5, 3), type = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b"), id = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

And again, additionaly to r2evans:

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)
   
df[, id:=NULL]

df[, .N, by=names(df)]

   start_id end_id type N
1:        1      2    a 1
2:        2      5    a 2
3:        1      3    b 2
```

**data:**

```
df = structure(list(start_id = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), end_id = c(2L, 
5L, 3L, 5L, 3L), type = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b"), id = 1:5), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```